# how to call function in seperate files js?

Tags: javascript

I define some functions in two file js, file1 and file2. In each files, all of the functions are inside a `$(document).ready(function(){});`. I carefully place file1 above file2 in a php file, and call one function from file1 in file2, but console returns undefined function. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functions are defined inside a document ready handler, then they only exist within that scope and are inaccessible anywhere else.

The simplest solution would be to *define* your functions outside of the document ready handler and *use* them inside the ready handler or inside each other:

**File 1:**

```
function myFunc() {
    myOtherOtherFunc();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    myOtherFunc();
});
```

**File 2:**

```
function myOtherFunc() {
}

function myOtherOtherfunc() {
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    myFunc();
});
```

It should be noted that this places the functions on the global scope and this should be kept to a minimum, so if you find that there is a lot you need to share between files, you should look into using namespacing or even something more sophisticated like a module loader (e.g. require.js).

Answer (score 0):

Because you're defining your functions inside another function, they aren't globals. Which is a *good* thing.

There are a couple of ways to approach this:

1. Make them globals (blech), or
2. Use an AMD mechanism like RequireJS, or
3. Use a single global that has references to all your functions

That last looks like this:

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};
$(document).ready(function() {
    MyApp.myFunction = function() {
        // ...
    };
});
```

Then you can call them from anywhere via `MyApp.myFunction()`.

Answer (score -1):

$(document).ready should be called on html page. I suggest you separate the functions in the respective js files and call these functions from document.ready on page. I think this should solve the problem.